# NoReverseMatch: Urlpatterns path name for route with int:pk

Tags: django, django-templates, url-pattern

I am trying to create a dashboard with multiple customers rendered in the template, and a link to their individual profile. I was wondering if there is a way to pass in the url name and object pk id using django url in my template.

This is my code so far and I am getting a NoReverseMatch error.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('product/', views.product, name='product'),
    path('customer/<int:pk>', views.customer, name='customer'),
]

<th><a href="{% url 'customer' %}">{{ customer.first_name }} {{ customer.last_name }}</a></th>
```

I understand that this is wrong but I cannot find the right way to do it. I am relatively new to django programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass keyword arguments to the url tag you pass `arg=value` to the tag

```
{% url 'customer' pk=customer.pk %}
```

[Please read the docs for the url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)